# Configure GNU LD to fill gaps with small objects

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

Context: I'm trying to fit a program in to a microcontroller that *just barely* fits, so I'm trying to save every last drop of wasted memory.

Suppose you have a program with data like this:

```
char arr1[7];
char arr2[7];
char x;
char y;
```

The linker will assemble those in-order, like this:

```
arr1    7
*fill*  1
arr2    7
*fill*  1
x       1
y       1

total   18
```

But `x` and `y` will fit in those gaps! You could assemble it like this and save a few bytes:

```
arr1    7
x       1
arr2    7
y       1

total   16
```

If you instruct the linker to sort objects by alignment (`SORT_BY_ALIGNMENT` etc), that sort of helps, since it will at least put all the small things at the end without gaps between them, but it doesn't allow it to fill gaps between aligned data elsewhere in the image.

Is there a way to convince the linker to cram small objects in the alignment holes left between bigger objects?

Comment: `#pragma pack(push,1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`?

Comment: In your example all the variables have alignment 1, and I would expect the total size of those 4 variables to always be 16, no matter in which order they are linked.